# Solr's Data Import Request Handler for update the index

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I want to index Dbpedia datasets into SOLR.

1. My schema for this purpose is: [schema.xml](https://gist.github.com/iCEAGE/6053552)
2. My DIH config is: [data-config.xml](https://gist.github.com/iCEAGE/6053564)

Everything is Okay but I want to have all "Types" not the last "Type".
Is there any way to update Solr with DIH? I don't mean Delta-import

More explanation:

```
<field column="rawLine" 
      regex="THE SAMPLE REGEX"
      groupNames="uri,types,prettyTypes" />
```

The above config is got every line and then is processed with that regex and finally (uri,types,prettyTypes) are filled with appropriate data. But for example for "Alabama" we have 6 lines in Dbpedia's datasets:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AdministrativeRegion> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Place> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> .
```

Now after these 6 lines are processed with DIH, there will be just 1 doc with (Alabama, owl#Thing)'s data and the other 5 types will be deleted.

Comment: Your qn is tough to understand. What do you mean by "not wanting last Type" and "update Solr with DIH"?

Comment: I added more explanation about my question.